# Simple versioning of each single file in git

Tags: git, version-control

Is there any way to have simple version number in format x.y per each single file in git repository? git-tag isn't solution in my case because I need to have on each commit incremented version of each single which is part of commit.
Let's say I have following files in my repository:

```
FileA.txt 1.0
FileB.java 1.5
FileC.md 1.1
```

Each file has own version and now I'm pushing commit which changes FileA.txt and FileB.java, so I want to have state as below:

```
FileA.txt 1.1
FileB.java 1.6
FileC.md 1.1
```

Additionally I want to get file from git repository by providing the version of single file i.e. `git show 1.0:FileA.txt` or `git checkout 1.0 FileA.txt`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need this?

Comment: are you trying to emulate cvs? It is done already https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cvsserver

Comment: Looks like you want [RCS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rcs/info).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth there is existing release management tool which works using this model where you specify version of each single file and the preference is to align git interface instead of release management tool

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer is No.

**Git for version control is based on the changes of each commit not each file.** And It record each version by a calculated checksum (sha-1 value), so it can’t use the version number as `x.y`.

For other information:

- You can use `git blame filename` to check what version of last commit for each line of the file.
- You can use `git log filename` to check which commit(s) changed the file.
- If the files are separately, you can manage them in different branches so that the files can be versioned separately.